# Change pheatmap plot background colour

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

Is there a way I can change the plot background of `pheatmap` plot in R from white to let say black

```
library(pheatmap)
# Create test matrix
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")
# Draw heatmapspheatmap(test)
pheatmap(test)
```

I tried,  but it was not succesful

```
 pheatmap(test , bg="black")
```

Or is there a way to combine `pheatmap` with `ggplot2` function of `theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'black'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the colors of grobs in the object generate by `pheatmap`:

```
p <- pheatmap(test)

library(grid)
# Set white color for dendrogram lines and for text
for (k in c(1,2,4,5)) {
  p$gtable$grobs[[k]]$gp <- gpar(col="white")
}
p$gtable$grobs[[6]]$children[[2]]$gp <- gpar(col="white", fontsize=10)
# Draw a black box behind the heatmap as background
grid.draw(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="black", lwd=0)))
# Draw the heatmap
grid.draw(p)
```

[image]

Edit. As suggested by @Keniajin, a shorter solution is:

```
grid.draw(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="black", lwd=0)))
grid.draw(p)
grid.gedit("layout", gp = gpar(col = "white", text = ""))
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, for those who don't like loops this worked `grid.draw(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="black", lwd=0)))
grid.draw(p) 
grid.gedit("layout", gp = gpar(col = "white",  text = ""))`

Comment: @Keniajin Hi. Thanks a lot for your nice suggestion. I edited my answer adding your code.